# Create another action menuitem in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to extend the funcionallity of the actions defined in a custom module view adding a new menuitem for it. I'm not sure how is defined the code for doing it.

The model used is: education.group

The module where is defined is: education.

[image]

```
<record id="education_group_mailing_action" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Generate group lists</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_education_group"/>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_education_group"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">action = records.generate_lists()</field>
</record>

<record id="education_group_mailing_action2" model="ir.default">
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_education_group" />
        <field name="field_id" eval="1" />
        <field name="json_value">False</field>
        <field name="name">Generate group lsts</field>
        <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
        <field name="key">action</field>
        <field name="model">education.group</field>
        <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,' + str(ref('education_group_mailing_action'))" />
    </record>
```

```
class EducationGroup(models.Model):
    _inherit='education.group'

   def generate_lists(self):
        print("HELLO!")
```

Anyone knows how to to it?
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Odoo12.0 then you have to do like this.

```
    <record id="new_action1" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">New Action</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_product_template" />
        <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_product_template" />
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">records.export_product()</field>
    </record>
    <record id="run_product_new_order_action2" model="ir.default">
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_product_template" />
        <field name="field_id" eval="1" />
        <field name="json_value">False</field>
        <field name="name">New Action</field>
        <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
        <field name="key">action</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,' + str(ref('new_action1'))" />
    </record>
```

If you are using Odoo13.0 then it will be like

```
       <record id="product_order_new_action1" model="ir.actions.server">
            <field name="name">New Action</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_product_template" />
            <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_product_template" />
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">records.sync_product(False)</field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Hey Adam, i tried the next code as I edited but is not working, I cannot see the new dropdown item, do you know what's happening? @Adam Strauss

Comment: which one ? first or second one?

Comment: I'm using Odoo12 So I tried the first one. I edited my code with the new try but still cannot see the dropdown list item. Thanks for help! @Adam Strauss

Comment: I need to use in the tree view, for launching the python funciton for selected records. @Adam Strauss

Answer (score 1):

Check this Code,

```
<record id="mail_mass_mailing_lists_action" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Generate group lists</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="mass_mailing.model_mail_mass_mailing_list"/>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="mass_mailing.model_mail_mass_mailing_list"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">action = records.generate_lists()</field>
</record>
```

Thanks