# Create item in Odoo V12 action dropdown

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to create a new item in this dropdown list for Odoo V12, but I'm nos sure how to define the template/record ... I need to generate a new option for calling a python function.
[image]

The model of the view is the next one: education.group
The module that contains this model is called: education

I tried the next code but I still have the issue. (I'm not sure if the view has to be defined like that).

```
 <record id="education_group_mailing_action" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Generate group lists</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="education.group"/>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="education.group"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">action = records.generate_lists()</field>
</record>
```

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit='education.group'

    def generate_lists(self):
        print("que pasa")
```

This is the error:

[image]

This is the model in the DB:

[image]

Anyone knows how to do it?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: In drop down list some are already mentioned, just follow those statements.

Comment: This code I dind't make it and I'm not able to search it in the proyect code. Could you help me? Thanks @SaisivaA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create another action menuitem in Odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707862/create-another-action-menuitem-in-odoo)

Comment: Yea it worked, this post was created before. Thanks for your help! @AdamStrauss

Answer (score 0):

in model_id you should pass model name, change your model_id like

```
<field name="model_id" ref="your_module_name.model_education_group"/>
<field name="binding_model_id" ref="your_module_name.model_education_group"/>
```

Comment: I edited the model, but I'm not able to do it. Could you help me? @Pruthvi Barot

Comment: I edited my answer pls check now and add your module name in `your_module_name`

Comment: I tried with education.education.group and still giving the error. @Pruthvi Barot

Comment: With this: education.model_education_group is not giving any error, but the action item does not appear in the dropdown list. @Pruthvi Barot

Comment: I tried now yes and the error is gone,but the item does not appear in the dropdown list, is needed to configure any view? @Pruthvi Barot