# Migrate the Action Button from openerp to odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have the following xml code which is the form view for the Action Button in more dropdown.

```
  <record id="loading_xml_formview_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Load RES</field>
        <field name="res_model">load.details</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('utiliy.group_lop_admin')])]"/>
    </record>



<record model="ir.values" id="load_file_more_item">
    <field name="name">Load File</field>
    <field name="model" eval="'rla.data'" />
    <field name="key" >action</field>
    <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
    <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,%d'%loading_xml_formview_action" />
</record>
```

I have tried migrating he same in oddo V13 as below. Its not working.

```
<record id="loading_xml_formview_action" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Load RES</field>
    <field name="type">load.details</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_rla_data"/>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_rla_data" />
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,%d'%loading_xml_formview_action" />
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('utiliy.group_nest_admin')])]"/>
</record>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create another action menuitem in Odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707862/create-another-action-menuitem-in-odoo)

Comment: I know when we call a method like ```<field name="code">records.sync_product(False)</field>``` . But in My case I need a new form while i click on that Action Method. I'm not sure how openerp handled it or do we need to write a method to create a new form in Odoo?

Comment: call your method and in your method write ` return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': 'Vehicles',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'res_model': 'fleet.vehicle',
            'domain': [('driver_id', '=', self.id)],
            'context': "{'create': False}"
        }` this code to open a view